# Where can I find the status of my OAuth Developer Verification request? (Google)

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

https://support.google.com/code/contact/oauth_app_verification

Per google's recent security change, I've completed the above OAuth Developer Verification form 7 days ago. However, I received no response or an e-mail to acknowledge receipt of this form from the Google Developers team.

Can anyone direct me to where I can find out the status of my request and/or a contact number or address so I can find out more?

Many, many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide some more information. For e.g. what were the scopes you are going to ask for, and if your application is for personal/public/gsuite use ?

If this is a personal app, you can just join the Google group [Risky Access Permissions By Unreviewed Apps](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/risky-access-by-unreviewed-apps).

Also have you verified your domain via the [Search Console](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home) ?

[Additional F.A.Q](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/7394288)

Edit #2. 
I let the team reviewing the app know and they will reach out to you when the review is done. Currently, there is no place to check for the status of a review.

Comment: Sure. We asked for following scopes:
Profile, email, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar

It's an application for public use. It will be embedded into retail websites to allow users to communicate with their contacts on listed items.

Comment: Sorry, and to finish off, we have verified our domain via the search console (both http://www.secondopinions.help and the https version). Our developer account is avirate8@gmail.com. If you could give me a contact address I can provide the project id and OAuth client Id.

Comment: @Rahul sir, can you please help me out on my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52561945/google-oauth-developer-verification-form-submitted-but-no-response-from-google

Comment: @Rahul I've also been waiting forever for this. Is it still not possible to check the state of the application?