# How can I contact the Google OAuth client verification team?

Tags: google-apps, google-oauth

I have submitted my Google app for verification but I have received no email confirmation or communication from Google regarding this. 
Is there a way to check the status and contact team?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming issue.

Comment: People have asked similar questions below for the same communities I've tagged. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44375002/where-can-i-find-the-status-of-my-oauth-developer-verification-request-google

Comment: I'd also love to have an answer to this question. Our application has gone through the verification process successfully, but our Oauth recently started warning about lack of verification due to a change in our dev redirects (localhost). This is extremely damaging to the appearance of our application and I would really love to talk to someone about the right way to propagate changes while avoiding an unverified state.

I've seen previous answers in this forum from Google engineers.

Comment: @MattMartin Thanks! If you find an answer somewhere do share it here. I called up Google Support but they asked me to buy Technical Support for $150 to get 'technical replies'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Google team that works on this:

Unfortunately, right now, there is no place to check on the status of your verification request. But we do plan to show it in the developer console.

Matt, when we do show the verification requests in developer console, at that time we would be able to allow you to edit and submit a new request before modifying the current client. For now, you should submit a new verification request if you need to modify anything on the clientID and we'll make those change once approved.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I will send my request to the email you have specified. Please mention this in the request form as it will be of great help to others!